# how to use a class which inherits from TabControl in .xaml?

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol

I want add a "new" Button in the top of the TabControl, like this:
[image]

So, I create a class MyTabControl inherits from TabControl:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace tabcontrol
{
    [TemplatePart(Name="PART_ExtraHeaderHost", Type=typeof(ContentPresenter))]
    public class MyTabControl : TabControl
    {
        #region Fields
        private const string ExtraHeaderHostTemplateName = "PART_ExtraHeaderHost";
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ExtraHeaderProperty = ExtraHeaderPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;
        private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey ExtraHeaderPropertyKey = DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("ExtraHeader", typeof(object), typeof(TabControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ExtraHeaderStringFormatProperty = ExtraHeaderStringFormatPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;
        private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey ExtraHeaderStringFormatPropertyKey = DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("ExtraHeaderStringFormat", typeof(string), typeof(TabControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ExtraHeaderTemplateProperty = ExtraHeaderTemplatePropertyKey.DependencyProperty;
        private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey ExtraHeaderTemplatePropertyKey = DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("ExtraHeaderTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(TabControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ExtraHeaderTemplateSelectorProperty = ExtraHeaderTemplateSelectorPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;
        private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey ExtraHeaderTemplateSelectorPropertyKey = DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("ExtraHeaderTemplateSelector", typeof(DataTemplateSelector), typeof(TabControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

        #endregion Fields

        #region Properties
        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
        public object ExtraHeader
        {
            get
            {
                return base.GetValue(ExtraHeaderProperty);
            }
            internal set
            {
                base.SetValue(ExtraHeaderPropertyKey, value);
            }
        }

        internal ContentPresenter ExtraHeaderPresenter
        {
            get
            {
                return (base.GetTemplateChild("PART_ExtraHeaderHost") as ContentPresenter);
            }
        }

        public string ExtraHeaderStringFormat
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)base.GetValue(ExtraHeaderStringFormatProperty);
            }
            internal set
            {
                base.SetValue(ExtraHeaderStringFormatPropertyKey, value);
            }
        }

        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
        public DataTemplate ExtraHeaderTemplate
        {
            get
            {
                return (DataTemplate)base.GetValue(ExtraHeaderTemplateProperty);
            }
            internal set
            {
                base.SetValue(ExtraHeaderTemplatePropertyKey, value);
            }
        }

        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
        public DataTemplateSelector ExtraHeaderTemplateSelector
        {
            get
            {
                return (DataTemplateSelector)base.GetValue(ExtraHeaderTemplateSelectorProperty);
            }
            internal set
            {
                base.SetValue(ExtraHeaderTemplateSelectorPropertyKey, value);
            }
        }


        #endregion Properties
    }
}
```

`PART_ExtraHeaderHost` is placed the "new" Button. In consideration of place other control later, so use `PART_ExtraHeaderHost` rather than a Button.

But now, I don't know how to use it and style it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, fix your fields to initialize them in the correct order

```
    private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey ExtraHeaderPropertyKey = DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("ExtraHeader", typeof(object), typeof(TabControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));
    private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey ExtraHeaderStringFormatPropertyKey = DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("ExtraHeaderStringFormat", typeof(string), typeof(TabControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));
    private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey ExtraHeaderTemplatePropertyKey = DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("ExtraHeaderTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(TabControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));
    private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey ExtraHeaderTemplateSelectorPropertyKey = DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("ExtraHeaderTemplateSelector", typeof(DataTemplateSelector), typeof(TabControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ExtraHeaderProperty = ExtraHeaderPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ExtraHeaderStringFormatProperty = ExtraHeaderStringFormatPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ExtraHeaderTemplateProperty = ExtraHeaderTemplatePropertyKey.DependencyProperty;
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ExtraHeaderTemplateSelectorProperty = ExtraHeaderTemplateSelectorPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;
```

add a `xmlns` declaration to your window with your class namepsace

```
 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:tabcontrol"
```

And use your class instead of the `TabControl` class

```
<local:MyTabControl ....>
```

Comment: I can't run it, could you have a try? Just place a `MyTabControl` in Window. There is a error.

Comment: @SubmarineX your problem is with the fields definitions.Note that you set `ExtraHeaderProperty` with `ExtraHeaderPropertyKey` before you created `ExtraHeaderPropertyKey` and so on with the rest of your properties ... 
Initialize all your public fields first and then your public fields, and you should be fine ...

Comment: Sorry, I have made a big mistakes that just copy the code of TabControl.